# Error when using insert in access: Could not Update; currently locked

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have a WebService that updates my access table from some terminals (10).
When I try to update I get this error from the error log:

```
Could not Update; Currently locked
```

Some terminals succeed and some do not.

I update like this:

```
using (Conn = new OleDbConnection(Work_Connect))
         {
            Conn.Open();
            foreach (DataRow R in ds.Tables["MyCount"].Rows)
            {
                    U_ID = ID;
                    U_Bar = R["Bar"].ToString().Trim();
                    U_Qty = R["Qty"].ToString().Trim();
                    U_Des = R["Des"].ToString().Trim();

                    SQL  = "INSERT INTO MyTbl(ID,Bar,Qty,Des)VALUES('";
                    SQL += Convert.ToInt32(ID) + "','" + U_Bar + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(U_Qty) + "','" + U_Des + "')";
                    OleDbCommand Cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn);
                    Cmd2.CommandText = SQL;
                    Cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
           }
           GC.Collect();
           return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

MsAccess has serious drawbacks for multi-user update. The Jet engine is not a database server, and will manage concurrence based on file system locking. If your problem is with a web service, I'd move the update to the server part, and implement queuing of simultaneous requests there. Thus, only the server, one process, will have access to the Access data. The other option is to use a real database server that will do that work for you. SQL Server Express is the usual option because it's easy to integrate, it's free as in beer, and is solid.

Also, if your problem happens always from the same terminals, that is, some terminals can never update anything, check the file access rights of these terminals' users to the database file, the lock file, and the database and lock file directory. Write rights are required for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Convert your query to a *parameterized query* to avoid any potential strangeness with quoting. (You are converting text to numbers and then enclosing them in single-quotes in the SQL statement. That makes no sense.)
2. Don't force garbage collection on each call. According to the MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx): "It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create performance issues."

Try something like this instead:

```
using (Conn = new OleDbConnection(Work_Connect))
{
    Conn.Open();
    foreach (DataRow R in ds.Tables["MyCount"].Rows)
    {
        U_ID = ID;
        U_Bar = R["Bar"].ToString().Trim();
        U_Qty = R["Qty"].ToString().Trim();
        U_Des = R["Des"].ToString().Trim();

        SQL  = "INSERT INTO MyTbl (ID,Bar,Qty,Des) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        using(OleDbCommand Cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn))
        {
            // Cmd2.CommandText = SQL;  redundant, the 'new' set the .CommandText
            Cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
            Cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", U_Bar);
            Cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDouble(U_Qty));
            Cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", U_Des);
            Cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    Conn.Close();
}
// GC.Collect();  // disabled for test purposes
return true;
```